# Google Custom Search - changing url without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-custom-search

I would like to implement the result only Google custom search similar like in [this page](http://googlecustomsearch.appspot.com/element/layoutdemo/results-only_form.html). 
If you look at the page and source code, you can understand how Google custom search is implemented. When someone enter search term and press the search button, it will not refresh the page,yet the result will be displayed. That is awesome. So, I want to implement that.

Also, when submit button is pressed the URL in address bar will not change. But, I want to add the query in the url when form is submitted for SEO purpose. For example if someone searches **world** the url should be changed to **index.html?q=world**, but without refreshing the page.

How to achieve it using javascript or jquery?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's built-in functionality to Google custom search.

Comment: Changing the URL on user input doesn't help with SEO.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in modern browsers using HTML5 history mechanism:
http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/

e.g. like this:

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
```

On your page you can have your own search button, and when user clicks you execute query programatically, then you change the address bar:

```
var element = google.search.cse.element.getElement('element1);
element.execute('news');
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/?q=news");
```